# Space between data when exporting excel file from datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this bug on my export file using Datatables. There are some unnecessary space between the data.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dataTablesWExport').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{
              extend: 'excelHtml5',
              exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        {
          extend: 'pdfHtml5',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible'
        }
    },
    'colvis'
    ],
    "order": []
});
    });
</script>
```

**Screeshot of the export file**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4gah.png

Comment: How is the source data provided, did you check it?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show some sample data from the HTML table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a row function to control which rows are exported (the rows with data) and which are not (the blank rows).

**Example**

Assume I have the following data in my table:

```
<table id="myTable" class="display nowrap dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Adélaïde Fleury</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Paris</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>London</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My DataTable object is defined like this:

```
  $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'excel',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [ 0, 1 ], // just for my demo
            rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
              return data[0];
            }
          }
        }
    ]
  } );
```

This is displayed as follows:

[image]

It uses a `rows` function to test each row. If the first cell in the row (`data[0]`) has data in it, then the row will be exported to Excel. But if the cell is blank, empty, or null, the row will not be exported:

[image]

**How It Works**

The row function returns a value of `true` or `false` for each row in the DataTable. JavaScript will therefore treat a non-blank value in `data[0]` as truthy - and therefore that row is returned.

So, `return data[0]` is just a more compact way of writing this:

```
if ( data[0].length > 0 ) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

**Data Arrays vs Data Objects**

My source data was taken directly from the HTML table, so it was provided as arrays of data (one array for each row): `[ 'John Smith', 'Accountant' ]`. This is why I used `data[0]` to check the contents of the first cell in each row.

If my data had been sourced from a JSON object, it may have looked different, for example:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "position": "Accountant"
},
{
  ...
}
```

In this case, `data[0]` would not work. I would need to use `data.name` instead.